# Find actual Centos6 path for %{_includedir} in spec file?

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm

I am trying to find out which path actually resolves to %{_includedir} in a Centos6 installation.

I understand that this is normally "/usr/include" but where can I find where it is actually set or somehow "echo" it?

Basically, a spec I am using has "%dir %{_includedir}/someFolder/someFile". Everything runs fine but I can't find "/usr/include/someFolder". I assume it has been created somewhere else and I am trying to find out where that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpmbuild --showrc` shows all marcos available, _includedir is one of them:

```
-14: _includedir        %{_prefix}/include
```

(no idea what -14 means).

Marcos are being set system-wide somewhere in `/etc/rpmrc` or `/etc/rpm/` or similar (was not able to find actual location, never needed it), and you can override them in `~/.rpmmacros` file.

See also: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Macros

Answer (score 5):

```
$ rpm -E '%{_includedir}'
/usr/include   # The actual location may vary
```

Comment: Just seeing this. Works better than the accepted answer so I have +1ed it. Keeping my acceptance on the previous since it came first and did get me the info I wanted.